# Стегно і бедро. Чи є різниця?

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, семантика

В німецькій і анґлійській мовах є різниця між словами hip/thigh, die Hüfte/der Schenkel.

В російській це все просто називають бедро.

Точно знаю, що на Прикарпатті кажуть "бедро" на зовнішню сторону верхньої частини ноги, а "стегно" — на частину ноги від тазостегнового до колінного суглоба. Це було б лоґічно: розрізняти дві різні частини тіла.

Але в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/steghno):

> СТЕГНО́, а, сер. Частина ноги людини або тварини від тазостегнового до колінного суглоба, а також зовнішня сторона верхньої частини ноги, тазу.
>
> [БЕДРО́](http://sum.in.ua/s/bedro), а, сер., рідко. Те саме, що стегно.

Чи є, все-таки, різниця між словами, а чи треба повністю довіряти СУМу, коли обираю, яке використати? Основне питання: чи є семантична різниця між словами "стегно" і "бедро"?

Answer (score 2):

стегно = частина ноги людини від тазостегнового до колінного суглоба, а також зовнішній бік верхньої частини ноги, тазу.

thigh = the part of the leg of the human body between the hip and the knee

thigh = стегно, в широкому сенсі

hip = the area below the waist and above the legs at either side of the body, or the joint which connects the leg to the upper part of the body

hip = таз, тазостегновий суглоб

hip = стегно у вузькому сенсі, наприклад:

"put hands on hips" = "покласти руки на стегна", оскільки ми не говоримо "покласти руки на таз [тазостегновий суглоб]"

У підсумку, семантичної різниці між словами "стегно" і "бедро", подібної англійським hip/thigh, - не вбачається.

В російській слова "бедро" й "стегно" використовуються майже з прямо зворотною частотою у порівнянні з українською ("стегно", "бедро"); також є слово "ляжка" (розм.), більш локалізоване ніж "бедро", й тим самим певною мірою наближене до "thigh", але останнє навряд чи ми вживатимемо в науковій статті поза межами лінгвістики/філології :)

Comment: Добрий день! Ваша відповідь справді помічна, лише один момент: на цьому сайті не вітаються відповіді без наведення джерел. Якби ви могли навести джерела, звідки ви берете інформацію, ця відповідь виглядала би дуже добре в межах цього форуму. Щоб додати джерела, треба натиснути edit і вказати перед кожним визначенням, яке ви наводите, звідки ви його берете. Якщо це будуть поважні словники, а не ґуґл транслейт і мінінґз - буде ще краще. Якщо ви зможете додати посилання (виділяєте слово і натискаєте на ланцюжок згори, коли редаґуєте) - взагалі ціни не буде такій відповіді.

Comment: Доведеться замінусувати відповідь до редаґування.

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю, що варто надавати перевагу слову "стегно". Шукаючи інформацію, я вводив слово "бедро" в пошуку та отримував варіанти, переважно, російською мовою. Також на сайті [Svoboda News](http://svoboda-news.com/svwp/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83-6/) знайшов наступне:

> Бедро – не українське слово, замість нього треба вживати стегно.

Та й якщо подивимося на Вікіпедії статтю про [ногу](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8), то бачимо:

> Нога анатомічно складається з трьох основних частин: стегна, гомілки і
>   стопи.

В свою чергу сама Вікіпедія посилається на Атлас анатомії людини (не зміг знайти український варіант цієї книги).

Тобто, якщо вам доведеться обирати, то правильним варіантом буде саме "стегно". Я так розумію, що слово "бедро" було запозичене з російської мови (хоч ЕСУМ цього не підтверджує), де воно [означає](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_3): "нижня або задня кінцівка людини чи тварини між тазобедренним та колінним суглобом", що відповідає значенню слова "стегно". Також на Вікіпедії українській статті про "стегно" відповідає російська стаття про "бедро".

Отже:

- "стегно" та "бедро" означають одну і ту ж частину тіла;
- потрібно надавати перевагу слову "стегно".

Comment: 1. Це не відповідь на моє питання. Я питав, чи ці слова синонімічні, а чи позначають різні частини тіла. 2. Якщо ЕСУМ цього не підтверджує, то це ваші особисті припущення, і така відповідь не задовільняє вимоги стека. Мінус один.

Comment: Це не мої особисті припущення, Олександр Пономарів (на якого тут чатсо посилаються) зазначив, що слово запозичене, а я просто припустив, що воно запозичене саме з російської і навів причини чого я так думаю.
На основі слів мовознавця я дав відповідь на ваше питання: надавайте перевагу слово "стегно", обидва слова означають одне і те ж, тобто вони синоніми (в словнику синонімів до слова "стегно" немає слова "бедро" т.к. воно не українське).

Comment: посилання на свобода-ньюз не працює.

Comment: Дивно, щойно спробував перейти за посиланням і у мене все працює:

http://svoboda-news.com/svwp/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83-6/

Comment: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /svwp/Ð²Ð¸Ð²Ñ‡Ð°Ð¹Ð¼Ð¾-ÑƒÐºÑ€Ð°Ñ—Ð½ÑÑŒÐºÑƒ-Ð¼Ð¾Ð²Ñƒ-6/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: стаття на вікі - дуже сумнівне джерело.

Comment: Згодний, але в цьому випадку є посилання на Атлас анатомії людини. На жаль, я не зміг знайти його український варіант, але якщо натраплю на нього, то обов'язково його додам.

Comment: @P.Vowk Добрий день,
ТИХИЙ Олекса. СЛОВНИК МОВНИХ ПОКРУЧІВ
Донецьк: Товариство ім. Олекси Тихого, 2009. – 130 с. http://torba.etnoua.info/files/Oleksa-Tyhyj_Slovnyk-movnyh-pokruchiv_VOvsijenko_2009.pdf 
дванадцята сторінка